# Remove item from screen after delete

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I had this working with react app but I am porting the project to next.js and it doesn't work for some reason. I am using [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation)

Custom hook:

```
import axios from "axios";
import useSwr from "swr";

export const useHttp = (url, token) => {
  const fetcher = (url, token) =>
    axios
      .get(url, { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token } })
      .then((res) => res.data);
  const { data, error } = useSwr(token ? [url, token] : null, fetcher);

  return {
    data: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error,
  };
};
```

In my page

```
  const { data, isError, isLoading } = useHttp(
    `http://localhost:8000/api/admin/bookings/${id}`,
    session.user.servertoken
  );


  const deleteBooking = async (id) => {
    //immediatly remove record from the screen before getting response from the server
    mutate(
      [
        `http://localhost:8000/api/admin/bookings/${id}`,
        session.user.servertoken,
      ],
      data.filter((d) => d._id !== id),
      false
    );
    try {
       const response = await axios.delete(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/admin/bookings/${id}`,
        { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + session.user.servertoken } }
       );
      mutate([
        `http://localhost:8000/api/admin/bookings/${id}`,
        session.user.servertoken,
      ]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

The button:

```
<Button
  variant="danger"
  onClick={() => deleteBooking(d._id)}
>
  Delete
</Button>
```

Absolutely nothing happens in terms of the ui though (record IS deleted in database). The record should disappear from the screen once I click on delete and the deleteBooking function runs.

*If I add this to my deleteBooking function it shows the correct data:

```
const filteredData = data.filter((d) => d._id !== id);
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't actually show you using `deleteBooking()` anywhere.

Comment: @foxes I have added the button code, hope that helps

Comment: I have no idea where the mutate function comes from. But in general you should never mutate state in react. React wont detect changes in your state if you mutate it, which means your component won rerender.

Comment: @StephanOlsen, please take a look here: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation

Comment: Seems like you need to pass the key when mutating, you're passing an array. It should just be `mutate(\`http://localhost:8000/api/admin/bookings/${id}\`, data.filter((d) => d._id !== id))` as far as I can tell.

Comment: The mutate needs to match the initial request in terms of structure. I have an array there because I have the url and the token `const { data, error } = useSwr(token ? [url, token] : null, fetcher);`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this library, so I don't know how it handles the keys internally when you provide an array as key. Either way there should be no reason to add the token to the key.

Comment: I have to send the auth token in the header of every request to the API otherwise authentication will basically fail and I won't be able to get the data from the server.

Comment: You're already doing that, the first parameter is just the key that the value will be stored on. No need to include the token here. Including the token in the key would also mean you would lose any cached values if the token changes.

Comment: @StephanOlsen, I managed to get this working using bound mutate. All I ended up having to do as a result was `mutate(data.filter((d) => d._id !== id));`